# How to extend a dictionary class

Tags: powershell, dictionary, extent

I would like to create a custom dictionary class in PowerShell (which temporary stores a configuration in a specific 3rd party application and retrieves it in another PowerShell session). Technically, I could also do this by creating a kind of `Set-MyConfigVariable -Key <key> -Value  <Value>` and  `Get-MyConfigVariable -Key <key>` cmdlets, but I would like to investigate if I can make in more user (author) frindly with a extended dictionary (and hook in the `getter`and `setter` methods).
In short, something that is discribed here in C#: [How to write a getter and setter for a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11583759/1701026)

```
Class MyStore: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String] {
    $h = @{}
    [string]$This([String]$Key) {
        get { write-host 'getting something'; return $h[$Key] }
        set { write-host 'setting something'; $h[$Key] = $Value }
    }
}

$MyStore = [MyStore]::new()
$MyStore['key'] = 'value'
$MyStore['key']
```

The above prototype fails at `[string]$This([String]$Key) {` (the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?) but probably also need a different implementation for the getter and setter (using `Update-TypeData`?).

How can this be done in PowerShell (if even possible)?
If not possible for a class, can it be done on an single instance (with dynamic keys)?

Comment: Best you can get from powershell is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717230/powershell-class-implement-get-set-property

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you're trying to override the index accessor on a dictionary? It's straight-up _impossible_ in 5.1 (due to the way powershell classes construct members), and an absolutely pain in 7.1 (from which it is possible). IMO the easiest way forward here is by far to write a custom dictionary implementation in C# and calling `Add-Type`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, "*Can you explain why you're trying to override the index accessor*", no I can't (lack of knowledge), I was just looking into a potential nice syntax for our framework.. Anyways, thanks for the information I don't think I will go further into this rabbit hole...

Comment: @iRon From the description it honestly sounds like you just need a... regular dictionary (or a hashtable)? No need to re-invent tested wheels :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, the difference with a regular dictionary is that I would like to hook in to the getter/setter to read and write my keys somewhere remote similar to a secret store but than with an easier syntax.

Comment: @iRon Gotcha. In that case, my original advice still stands: write the subtype in C#, and run `Add-Type` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***PowerShell code***, using custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es, has the following **limitations** as of PowerShell 7.3.4:

- There's generally *no* support for property *getters* and *setters* - [GitHub issue #2219](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219) proposes adding support for them.
- For now, getters and setters for *regular* properties can be *emulated*, using [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Member) with a `ScriptProperty` member, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365941/45375).<sup>Tip of the hat to [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).</sup>
- However, there is ***no* workaround for implementing *parameterized* properties, as is required for implementing *indexers***.

***C# code***, ad hoc-compiled with [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Type), **offers a solution**:

- *Deriving* your custom class from `Dictionary[String,String]` - as you've attempted - is problematic, because it requires *hiding* the base class members with the `new` keyword, which in PowerShell code - at least as of PowerShell 7.3.4 - isn't fully supported - see [GitHub issue #19649](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19649).
- However, you can make your custom class *wrap* a dictionary type, and provide access to it via type-specific indexer (parameterized property), into which you can hook PowerShell script blocks to execute.

See the following **sample implementation**:

```bash
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;
public class CustomDict
{
  // The dictionary to wrap.
  Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new ();
  // The hook script blocks.
  ScriptBlock _getHook, _setHook;
  // Constructor
  public CustomDict(ScriptBlock getHook = null, ScriptBlock setHook = null)
  {
    _getHook = getHook; _setHook = setHook;
  }
  // Implement an indexer that provides access to the wrapped 
  // dictionary's, while also executing the "event"-hook script blocks.
  public string this[string key]
  {
      get { 
        _getHook?.Invoke(_dict, key);
        return _dict[key]; 
      }
      set { 
        _setHook?.Invoke(_dict, key, value);
        _dict[key] = value;
      }
  }
}
'@

# Construct an instance with both GET and SET hooks (script blocks).
$o = [CustomDict]::new(
  { param($dict, $key) Write-Verbose -Verbose "getting entry '$key'" }, 
  { param($dict, $key, $value )Write-Verbose -Verbose "setting '$key' to '$value'" }
)

# Create an entry...
$o['foo'] = 'bar'
# ... and report its value
$o['foo']
```

Output:

```
VERBOSE: setting 'foo' to 'bar'
VERBOSE: getting entry 'foo'
bar
```

Note:

- The script blocks passed as hooks execute in a *child* scope of the caller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights and dictionary class wrapper! Based on the suggestion from @MathiasR.Jessen, I was trying to do something similar but couldn't  get the C# PowerShell hooks as nicely as you did due to my limited C# knowledge.